# Left pad an alphanumeric string that includes special characters with 0s to make the numeric part a total of 5 digits?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to left pad an alphanumeric string with 0s to make the numeric part of the string a total of 5 digits.

For eg:

1843Q -> 01843Q

691B -> 00691B

My problem arises when special characters are introduced in the string.

For eg:

4361G-3 -> 04361G-3

What my code does:

4361G-3 -> 04361G-

My code is

```
    str1 = "-*"
    str = Job
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
     chr = Mid(str, i, 1)
     result = str Like str1
     If IsNumeric(chr) Then
      If result = False Then
       strg = strg & chr
      End If
     ElseIf isalpha(chr) Then
      If result = False Then
       strg2 = strg2 & chr
     End If
     ElseIf chr = "-" Then
      strg3 = strg3 & chr
     ElseIf strg3 Like "-" Then
      strg3 = strg3 & chr
     ElseIf strg3 Like "[-]*" Then
      strg3 = strg3 & chr
     End If
Next i
strg = Format(strg, "00000") & strg2 & strg3
Job = strg
```

How do I need to change this to get what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a simpler way to write your function.  Here is an Immediate window session demonstrating VBA functions you can use.

```vb
strFoo = "1843Q"
? Val(strFoo)
 1843 
? CStr(Val(strFoo))
1843
? Len(CStr(Val(strFoo)))
 4 
? Mid(strFoo, Len(CStr(Val(strFoo))) + 1)
Q
? Right(String(5, "0") & CStr(Val(strFoo)), 5)
01843
? Right(String(5, "0") & CStr(Val(strFoo)), 5) & _
    Mid(strFoo, Len(CStr(Val(strFoo))) + 1)
01843Q

' test with another value ...
strFoo = "4361G-3"
? Right(String(5, "0") & CStr(Val(strFoo)), 5) & _
    Mid(strFoo, Len(CStr(Val(strFoo))) + 1)
04361G-3
```

I'm too lazy to actually write the function.  Give it a try yourself if you want.  If you run into trouble, show us your code, the error message, and indicate which line triggers the error.

Comment: Thank You HansUp. I am actually a newbie to VB. The set of VBA functions that you mentioned did the trick.